# Is there an easier way to test suricata has enough resources to run without losing packets?

Tags: network, ids, logging

I'd like to see the effect of changing my Suricata hardware and software, and in particular make sure I can determine the rate above which I'll start to lose data. I'm running ESXi with 20 cores and lots of RAM but I also need to be able to run in extremely limited hardware in some cases also.

A clumsy way to do this is to use `tcpreplay --mbps xxx` and try different values for `xxx`. I can look at the log files using `wc -l *.log` and see that I'm getting fewer log messages when, in my not very good setup, `xxx` is between 10 and 20.

I do not see the string `kernel_drops` in any of these log messages.

Isn't there a more elegant way to find the rate at which I just start to lose the ability to process packets?